# Apex Limits.getQueueableJobs() in test class

Tags: apex, code-coverage, queueable-apex

I have a class where there is a if condition as below

```
if (Limits.getQueueableJobs() == Limits.getLimitQueueableJobs())
```

In real time its called from batch context and Limits.getLimitQueueableJobs() is always 1.
In order for some testing, i need to cover the lines under this if block in a test class.
How can i manually set the values for these without creating any queueable class or calling any existing queueable class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following:

1. Ensure that you are not using static methods, since these cannot be overridden. If the class is full of static methods, make them non-static, add singleton management (a static reference to an instance of the class and a static getter that lazily manages and returns that instance) and have your production code use the singleton.
2. Make the class `virtual`.
3. Refactor this condition into a separate `virtual` method, let's say 'isAtQueueableLimits'.
4. In your unit test class create a custom extension of the class under test (as a nested class) that overrides this new method, 'isAtQueueableLimits', to return true.
5. In the unit test for this logic use the nested class instead of the class under test.

Because the condition logic has been overridden in just this one test you can ensure you still cover the original behaviour but can get in and simulate the alternative condition in another test.